# Im having problems trying to URL encode a databinder result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a repeater to show a list of strings- I am having issues trying to url encode the links (replace the spaces with %20 etc.)
I initially wrote a small method:

```
public string encodePath(string path)
{
    string newPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path);
    return newPath;
}
```

and then tried

```
<%# encodePath(Eval(Container.DataItem, "Area"))%>
```

but I am getting a compilation error "CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(string, string)' has some invalid arguments"

I also tried to just use the util without the method

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Area"))
```

As I believe it will be faster - but also got an error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
<%# encodePath(Eval("Area") as string)%>
```

or

```
<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Area") as string) %>
```

Comment: thanks - for some reason the method is still not working - but I was able to use the inline option.